# Using Navigation with AndroidX

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I want to create an Android Project using AndroidX Jetpack Libaries. However this Library [(Navigation)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) isn't available in the androidx package yet.

### My gradle dependencies

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0-alpha1"
def room_version = "2.0.0-alpha1"
def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
def mat_version = "1.0.0-alpha1"

// Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"

// Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

// Navigation
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing-ktx:$nav_version"

// Material Design
// implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$mat_version"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
```

I also have `compileSdkVersion 'android-P'`

### But when i want to start the APP i get this Error

```
Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
```

Then i go to `Navigate -> Class` which results
[image]

I often tried `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project`

### In my gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=false
android.useAndroidX=true
```

If i set `enableJetifier` to true the whole android.support v4 library is missing and navigation doesn't work either because android.support.v4.Fragment is missing (and other stuff).

Comment: This is a [known issue with AndroidX](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79667498)